# Javascript, jQuery: Change a certain word of a div into a <span> with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to turn this

```
<div id='theDiv'>I love potatoes</div>
```

into this:

```
<div>I love <span id='potatoesSpan'>potatoes</span></div>
```

with this function:

```
turnWordIntoSpan("#theDiv","potatoes");
```

So the function would search for the `searchedWord`(in this case `potatoes`) in the element with the id `wrapId`(in this case `#theDiv`) and replace it for a `span`  with the id `"#" + searchedWord + "Span"`.

How can I do it? I had some methods presented to me that seem way too complicated and that is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Have considered maybe searching like you do and then moving the contents in side that div inside to newly created span and deleting the original div markup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `html()` and `replace()` for that

```js
function turnWordIntoSpan(id, replace) {
  $(id).html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(replace, "<span id='potatoesSpan'>$&</span>");
  })
}

turnWordIntoSpan("#theDiv", "potatoes");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='theDiv'>I love potatoes</div>
```

**Update :** The above solution cause several problems, that it will remove event handler from inner elements. So you can do something like this, which only replace content in `textNode`

```js
function turnWordIntoSpan(id, replace) {
  var add = 0;
  $(id).contents()
    // contents() for getting descentant including textnode
    .each(function(i) {
      // each() for iterating over elements
      if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        // checking node is textnode  
        var child = this;
        var parent = this.parentNode;
        // getting it's parent node
        var split = this.nodeValue.split(replace);
        // spliting string based on the replace parameter

        if (replace.length > 1) {
          split.forEach(function(v, ind) {
            // iterating over splited string
            if (ind == 0)
              child.nodeValue = v;
            else {
              var text = document.createTextNode(v);
              // creating textnode
              parent.insertBefore(text, child.nextSibling);
              // insering into parent
              child = text;
            }
            if (ind != split.length - 1) {
              var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
              // creating span
              sp1.style.color = 'red';
              sp1.innerHTML = replace;
              // setting span content
              parent.insertBefore(sp1, child.nextSibling);
              // insering span into parent node
              child = sp1;
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
}

turnWordIntoSpan("#theDiv", "potatoes");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='theDiv'>I love potatoes hjhghgh potatoes bvbb <span>jhjghjj</span> potatoes hhhhh
  <div>jhjh</div>dhsjhdjshdjshj potatoes hgdhgh xcxcxcx</div>
```